# Instagram - How to get media based on a given hashtag?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to write an Instagram app which among others will let me get media based on a hashtag.
I already finished it, and only then noticed this message from Instagram in the [developer page](https://www.instagram.com/developer/register/).

> Starting 10/1/2017, all permissions other than the basic permission will be unavailable to submit for or obtain.

Query by hashtag needs the public_content permission.
Looks like this is not possible anymore.

Are there any other options? I tried to look for similar functionality with Facebook [graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference) but didn't find anything interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this PHP library: 
https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-php-scraper

or Java library:
https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-java-scraper

Example:

https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-php-scraper/blob/master/examples/getMediasByTag.php

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$instagram = \InstagramScraper\Instagram::withCredentials('username', 'password', '/path/to/cache/folder');
$instagram->login();

$medias = $instagram->getMediasByTag('youneverknow', 20);
$media = $medias[0];
echo "Media info:\n";
echo "Id: {$media->getId()}\n";
echo "Shotrcode: {$media->getShortCode()}\n";
echo "Created at: {$media->getCreatedTime()}\n";
echo "Caption: {$media->getCaption()}\n";
echo "Number of comments: {$media->getCommentsCount()}";
echo "Number of likes: {$media->getLikesCount()}";
echo "Get link: {$media->getLink()}";
echo "High resolution image: {$media->getImageHighResolutionUrl()}";
echo "Media type (video or image): {$media->getType()}";
$account = $media->getOwner();
echo "Account info:\n";
echo "Id: {$account->getId()}\n";
echo "Username: {$account->getUsername()}\n";
echo "Full name: {$account->getFullName()}\n";
echo "Profile pic url: {$account->getProfilePicUrl()}\n";
```

Comment: Looks good. Do you know what is the rate this api will work? Are there any limits?

Comment: @Tomer yes. From library users's experience: regular Instagram limits (https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/)

Comment: I am not sure I understand something. Are those limits for all users of that lib? If those limits are enforced by Instagram. this means that the requests are done by using some kind of key authorized by them. if the lib does not require any key, why those limits apply?

Comment: Also the limits are live account limits or sandbox limits?

Comment: Are those limits for all users of that lib? No. This limits for logged in user (library uses instagram web, so it is like you login in web and making requests)

Answer (score 1):

According to the blog post on facebook, they will be deprecating public content apis on December 11, 2018.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/instagram-graph-api-updates/

I also didn't find anything on the graph api for this use case so it looks like you will be out of luck.

Answer (score -2):

Id love to know about this as well, we have been developing and didnt know about the cut off to these permissions. Looking for a solution to retrieve public images based on a hashtag.

Following!

Comment: This answer does not help in solving the problem